# Desplazarse y arrastrar elementos en CollectionView Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Tengo una CollectionView con varios elementos y quiero que el usuario pueda arrastrarlos y ordenarlos a gusto (para esto utilizo DragGestureRecognizer), pero cuando la lista es larga y uno quiere desplazarse hacia abajo para ver el resto de los elementos a veces me detecta directamente el DragStartingCommand y no me deja desplazarme.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, es importante que nos muestres el código que tienes o has intentado para solventar tu problema. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/586211/edit) tu pregunta y agregarlo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.